# Google signIn tokenId is invalid_token

Tags: android, google-signin, google-client

I need to get google+ signIn tokenId.

Here is my code:

```
var mGSO = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(WEB_CLIENT_ID)//from developer console
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build()
            mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
                    .enableAutoManage(mActivity, this)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, mGSO)
                    .build()

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)
        var tokenId = result.signInAccount.idToken
    }
```

So I successfully get tokenId, but when I try to check it here (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=) I receive message:

```
{
 "error": "invalid_token",
 "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}
```

Token the same every time I try to get it!
What is happening?
Any idea how to fix this?

**UPDATE**

found this issue: https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2/issues/61

> I was using the wrong google token from my sign-in on iOS. I
>   originally used user.authentication.idToken which is wrong, and will
>   not work.
>
> The correct token is user.authentication.accessToken.

but i cant find any similar accessToken at GoogleSignInResult object....

**UPDATE 2**

i am using debug apk.
here is my button click code:

```
fun onGooglePlusClicked(v: View) {
        val signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient)
        mActivity?.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)
    }
```

Comment: Did you use firebase Auth in this for login

Comment: no, only google+ login

Comment: Make sure that file is in the google-services.json in the correct position.That inside the app folder

Comment: it is correct and placed at correct place

Comment: Where do you get the WEB_CLIENT_ID ?Which console Firebase or any other

Comment: from google developer console, this client id for web client. please, take a look for update question

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin this is how we can integrate google sign from the Android now. I think google is now integrated all their services to firebase

Comment: i am using firebase console, but i dont need to use firebaseAuth, all other code - the same as from your link

Comment: So you go the WEB_CLIENT_ID  from firebase ?

Comment: yep, it was "autogenerated"

Comment: Did  you using a signed apk now ,debug and signed version have separate SHA1 key

Comment: Can you share code of the button click (intent call )?

Comment: please take a look for update

Comment: String tokenId = result.getIdToken(); this is how to get the token id fro the result try

Comment: result.signInAccount.idToken - this is the same, but in Kotlin. in fact this token is tooooo long

Comment: I am already found an answer )
anyway - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was founded here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth

key words: **GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()**

so, here is my updated code:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)

        Observable.create(Observable.OnSubscribe<String> {
                    var **accessTokent** = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity!!, result.signInAccount.account, "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN)
                    //send token to server
                })
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe()
    }
```

hope this will help someone :)

Answer (score 4):

**Very important thing**

Google needs to update the documentation, because it is misleading.
Either you are on iOS, or Android, you have to send the **accessToken** to the backend and **not the idToken**

You can get the accessToken from user object (e.g. val accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken)

For example, if you want to get user info, try this GET request:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token={access_token}

Comment: Not anymore access_tokens are deprecated as per backend documents and id_token should be used. Also added my answer here, refreshing the token does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Answer in 2021:
I've had the same problem.
For me clearing app data completely solved the issue.
Seemed like an old expired token got stuck.
Also the **id token** should be verified here
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day bro! Why didn't they show just "expired" error?!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was testing this in Unity and I copied the `idToken` value that I printed in logcat. Turns out, there is some character or size limit (1024 bytes?) for a line in either adb logcat or Unity's `Debug.Log()` method. So the printed token value was getting truncated. What I did then for testing was that I copied the token value to clipboard during runtime and then checked again with the tokeninfo endpoint `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=` and it was accepted.